Host Filtering in Rust jsonrpsee Server: Allow All Connections for Relay Nodes, Restrict to Localhost for Others
I'm using the jsonrpsee crate in Rust to implement an RPC server. I want to set up host filtering in such a way that:

The relay node can receive RPC calls from any node.
Other nodes should only respond to RPC calls from the relay node and localhost.

Here's my current code:
use jsonrpsee::http_server::{ServerBuilder, ServerHandle};
use std::error::Error;
use tower::{ServiceBuilder, layer::util::HostFilterLayer};

async fn start_rpc_server(port: String, is_relay_node: bool) -> Result<ServerHandle, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let rpc = RpcServerImpl::new();

    let host_filter = HostFilterLayer::new(["localhost", "127.0.0.1:8081"]).unwrap();

    let middleware = ServiceBuilder::new().layer(host_filter);

    if is_relay_node {
        let server = ServerBuilder::default().build(format!("0.0.0.0:{}", port)).await.map_err(Box::new)?;
        let addr = server.local_addr().unwrap();
            info!("Starting Relay node with RPC at {:?}", addr);
        return Ok(server.start(rpc.into_rpc()));
    } else {
        let server = ServerBuilder::default().set_http_middleware(middleware).build(format!("0.0.0.0:{}", port)).await.map_err(Box::new)?;
        let addr = server.local_addr().unwrap();
            info!("Starting local RPC server at {:?}", addr);
        return Ok(server.start(rpc.into_rpc()));
    }
}

I’m not sure how to configure HostFilterLayer to allow all incoming connections for the relay node while restricting other nodes to just localhost and the relay node.
Questions:

How can I configure HostFilterLayer to allow any incoming connection when is_relay_node is true?
If HostFilterLayer isn't suitable for this, is there an alternative way to implement this kind of conditional host filtering with jsonrpsee?

Thanks in advance for any help!
